# Complex Linq Query Update as DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

There are A and B tables that are related to each other. I want to create a linq query that will update the Status value in the A table if the entire row of relationship lines with the AID column in the B table is equal to or smaller than today's date in the Date field.

For example, according to the table below, the Status values of the rows with ID value 1 (AAA) and 2 (BBB) in Table A will be 1. Its Status value will not change because the line with ID value 3 (CCC) is not smaller than the current date of all the related rows in the B table.

How can I write the most stable and performance linq query?

```
Today : 2018-7-10

A Table
ID Name Status
1  AAA  0
2  BBB  0
3  CCC  0

B Table
ID AID Date
6  1   2018-5-3
7  2   2018-6-2
8  2   2018-6-4
9  3   2018-10-12
10 3   2018-7-7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Grouping TableB on AID
2. Selecting the "Max" date in each group.(Each unique AID)
3. Compares the selected dates with the corresponding Id in Table A.
4. Sets the Status value to true if the date is less or equal to the current date.

   ```
       TableB.GroupBy(x => x.AId).Select(group => new { identifier = group.Key, MaxDate = group.Max(m => m.Date) }).ToList().ForEach(y =>
       {
           if (y.MaxDate <= DateTime.Now.Date)
           {
               TableA.Where(g => g.Id == y.identifier).First().Status = true;
           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. This will select AIDs from Table B where Date is samller than now.
2. we select records from table A where its ID is in List from
   previous step
3. Then we update Status value

   A.Where ( a => B.Where( b => b.Date <= DateTime.Now).Select(b => b.AID).Contains(a.ID)).ForEach( a => a.Status = 1 )

Comment: Unless the date area of all related AID lines of Table B is smaller than today's date, no update should be done. For example, the status area of BBB lines of Table A which is related to BID 7 and 8 will be updated. But status area of CCC won't be updated.

Comment: EF will take care of that for you if are are using LINQ to EF
you can check generated query in application output or sql profiler if you are using MsSql

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Fetching those aS Who meet the condition. */
var aList1=(from b in dbset.Bs.Where(x=>x.Date<DateTime.Now)//TimeZone may vary
          join a in dbSet.As
          on b.AID equals a.ID
          select a);

/*Fetching those aS Who don't meet the condition. */
var aList2=(from b in dbset.Bs.Where(x=>x.Date>=DateTime.Now)//TimeZone may vary
          join a in dbSet.As
          on b.AID equals a.ID
          select a);

/*Removing those aS from list1 which occured in list2 */
var aFinalList=(aList1.Except(aList2)).ToList();

/*Updating status */
aFinalList.ForEach(x=>x.Status=1);
aFinalList.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupJoin` extension in `Lambda` to `Join` the `A` and `B` tables then use `All` extension with your condition (date <= Today or any condition) then update the `Status`. Something like,

```
var lstResult = lstA.GroupJoin(lstB, a => new { a.Id }, b => new { Id = b.AId }, (a, b) => new { a, b })
                .Select(x => 
                {
                    if (x.b.All(y => y.Date <= DateTime.Now)) //Actual condition here.
                    {
                        x.a.Status = true;
                        return x.a;
                    }
                    else return x.a;
                });
```

[C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMLRhD) with sample data.